# How to make separator in pandas read_csv more flexible wrt whitespace, for irregular separators?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, whitespace

I need to create a data frame by reading in data from a file, using `read_csv` method. However, the separators are not very regular: some columns are separated by tabs (`\t`), other are separated by spaces. Moreover, some columns can be separated by 2 or 3 or more spaces or even by a combination of spaces and tabs (for example 3 spaces, two tabs and then 1 space).

Is there a way to tell pandas to treat these files properly?

By the way, I do not have this problem if I use Python. I use:

```
for line in file(file_name):
   fld = line.split()
```

And it works perfect. It does not care if there are 2 or 3 spaces between the fields. Even combinations of spaces and tabs do not cause any problem. Can pandas do the same?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can use either a regex or `delim_whitespace`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> for line in open("whitespace.csv"):
...     print repr(line)
...     
'a\t  b\tc 1 2\n'
'd\t  e\tf 3 4\n'
>>> pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  1  2
1  d  e  f  3  4
>>> pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  1  2
1  d  e  f  3  4
```

Comment: You can also use `skipinitialspace` to skip initial space

Comment: how does it work, when i have a `txt.file` and the Format that I have a number followed by at least two whitespaces? the formula `delimiter=r"\d\d\s\s+`does not work

Comment: @PV8: in that case your delimiter is still only `\s+` or `\s{2,}` . Don't include an expression for the field `\d\d` in the delimiter! Delimiter is only the delimiter! Field is everything between delimiters (or quotes).

Comment: How to access the single element from the list? If i do like this df = pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header=None, delim_whitespace=True), 
print(df[0]) only prints the first element 0 but it doesnt print next element if i do print(df[1]) isnt it a list?

Comment: 'r' is redundant in delimiter=r"\s+", you can use    delimiter="\s+"

Answer (score 21):

```
>>> pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header = None, sep = "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+")
```

would use any combination of any number of spaces and tabs as the separator.

Answer (score 4):

Pandas has two csv readers, only is flexible regarding redundant leading white space:

```
pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
```

while one is not

```
pd.DataFrame.from_csv("whitespace.csv")
```

Neither is out-of-the-box flexible regarding trailing white space, see the answers with regular expressions. Avoid delim_whitespace, as it also allows just spaces (without , or \t) as separators.

Answer (score 2):

We may consider this to take care of all the combination and zero or more occurrences.

```
pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header = None, sep = "[ \t]*,[ \t]*")
```