# How to read file with space separated values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I try to read the file into pandas.
The file has values separated by space, but with different number of spaces
I tried:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=' ')
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make separator in read\_csv more flexible wrt whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace)

Comment: result = pd.read_table('file.csv', sep='\s+')

Answer (score 242, accepted):

add `delim_whitespace=True` argument, it's faster than regex.

Comment: should add that, and remove `delimiter=' '` as they are mutually exclusive in recent versions.

Comment: @matanster: `delimiter=' '` is very brittle, it says to expect one and only one space. No tabs, newsline, multiple spaces, nonbreaking whitespaces, combination of these etc. `delimiter='\s+'` is what pandas recommends and is more robust.

Comment: `sep="\s+"` argument also works

Comment: From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html): "Deprecated since version 2.2.0: Use `sep="\s+"` instead."

Answer (score 56):

you can use regex as the delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
```

Comment: This helps when you have more than just a space as delimiter. In current versions one should add `engine = "python"` to avoid a warning.

Comment: Sorry for commenting old reply here, what does `r` before `"\s+"` mean?

Comment: @AlphaF20 it means read as raw string literal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals

Answer (score 4):

Pandas read_fwf for the win:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(file_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a regular expression as a delimiter for read_table also, and it is fast :).

```
result = pd.read_table('file', sep='\s+')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get text parsing to work using the accepted answer (e.g if your text file contains non uniform rows) then it's worth trying with Python's csv library - here's an example using a user defined [Dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect):

```
 import csv

 csv.register_dialect('skip_space', skipinitialspace=True)
 with open(my_file, 'r') as f:
      reader=csv.reader(f , delimiter=' ', dialect='skip_space')
      for item in reader:
          print(item)
```

Comment: That's not true. It works with python 3.8 and pandas. The question asks for reading a text file in pandas.

Comment: Ah sorry - I have updated my answer to account for this.