# Reading text file without any delimiter in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file its content is like below:

```
H26      1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
H26 5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
H26                                                                        

A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4195081 88 68 68 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 67 68 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 66 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 87 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.5
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112380 86 58 96 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -2112380 86 57 99 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112280 86 57101 264340.6 4122580.8 370.3
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112280 86 57101 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112180 85 58102 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -2112380 86 58103 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51120 80   1  -2122179 82 51 67 264331.3 4122588.1 370.0
A           416.0  2008.51120 80   1  -2122279 82 51 69 264331.3 4122588.1 370.0
```

I would like to divide it to columns like:

```
 2008.5 264363.6 4122568.8
 2008.5 264363.6 4122568.8
 2008.5 264363.6 4122568.8
```

I tried pandas like below but it only output one column:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("data.txt", header=4)
```

Any help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to read the documentation related to the read_csv method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read file with space separated values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632075/how-to-read-file-with-space-separated-values-in-pandas)

Comment: No, it does not. df = pandas.read_csv("data.txt", header=4, delim_whitespace=True)  gives this error:                                                                                           pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 12 fields in line 27, saw 13

Comment: Try: `pd.read_csv('data.txt', skiprows=3, delim_whitespace=True, header = None)`

Comment: Is your data different from `data.txt` file in [this implementation](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/MagnificentSpatialSyntax) which runs okay?

Comment: But, do you see that this implementation runs successfully and prints out the Dataframe?  Try it by pressing the green run button at the top middle.

Comment: You are right @DarryIG my mistake the following data has row like                                      A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4195081 88 68168 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6    which should be 68 68 rather than 68168

Comment: The last message was incomplete, i.e.  'the following data has row like'.

Comment: You are right @DarryIG my mistake the following data has row like A 416.0 2008.51114 80 1 -4195081 88 68168 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6 which should be 68 68 rather than 68168

Comment: Not sure.  Could you update your data in your post.  Hard to tell in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-fwf-reader)

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s = """
H26      1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
H26 5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
H26                                                                        

A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4195081 88 68 68 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 67 68 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 66 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 87 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.6
A           416.0  2008.51114 80   1  -4194881 88 65 69 264363.6 4122568.8 370.5
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112380 86 58 96 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -2112380 86 57 99 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112280 86 57101 264340.6 4122580.8 370.3
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112280 86 57101 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -1112180 85 58102 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51117 80   1  -2112380 86 58103 264340.6 4122580.8 370.2
A           416.0  2008.51120 80   1  -2122179 82 51 67 264331.3 4122588.1 370.0
A           416.0  2008.51120 80   1  -2122279 82 51 69 264331.3 4122588.1 370.0"""

f = io.StringIO(s)
cols = [(19,30),(56,65),(65,75)]
df = pd.read_fwf(f,colspecs=cols,skiprows=[0,1,2,3],header=None)

df.loc[8:]
             0         1          2
8   2008.51117  264340.6  4122580.8
9   2008.51117  264340.6  4122580.8
10  2008.51117  264340.6  4122580.8
11  2008.51117  264340.6  4122580.8
12  2008.51120  264331.3  4122588.1
13  2008.51120  264331.3  4122588.1
```