# read in .txt file , transform into pandas dataframe, but spaces seperating value vary in number of spaces

Tags: python, pandas

This script reads in a txt file and creates a df, but the 'sep' argument I want to handle values that may be seperated by 1 space or more, so when I run the script above I get many columns with NaN.

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_file,header = None, sep=' ')
```

example txt file

```
blah blahh    bl
blah3 blahhe      ble
```

I want there to just be 3 columns so i get

```
Col_a  col_b   col_c
blah   blahh    bl
blah3  blahhe   ble
```

Comment: Try `df = pd.read_csv(data_file,header = None, sep='\s+', names='Col_a Col_b Col_c'.split(' '))` using regex for one or more space characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex as the delimiter:

```
pd.read_csv(data_file, header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", names='Col_a Col_b Col_c'.split(' '))
```

Or you can use `delim_whitespace=True` argument, it's faster than regex:

```
pd.read_csv(data_file, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names='Col_a Col_b Col_c'.split(' '))
```

Reference: [How to read file with space separated values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632075/how-to-read-file-with-space-separated-values-in-pandas)