# Pandas reads the txt file as 1 column except header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file with following data;

```
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
"2" "222" "0.111" "b1" "19.11" "17.96" "2.85" ""
"3" "333" "0.123" "b2" "42.79" "26.68" "2.85" ""
"4" "444" "0.105" "b3" "17.28" "16.50" "2.85" ""
"5" "555" "0.106" "b4" "18.74" "19.78" "2.88" ""
"6" "666" "0.107" "b5" "5.79" "9.93" "2.88" ""
```

I am trying to read file with pandas with following code;

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt",sep="\t",quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

When I try to get columns with `room_file.columns` it print this;

```
Index(['"uid" "raum_code" "tuerschild" "raumbezeichung" "raumflaeche" "raumumfang" "raumhoehe" "Comments"'], dtype='object')
```

But the df output looks just 1 column;

```
    "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
0   "2" "222" "0.111" "b1" "19.11" "17.96" "2.8...
1   "3" "333" "0.123" "b2" "42.79" ...
2   "4" "444" "0.105" "b3" "17.28" "16.50" "2...
3   "5" "555" "0.106" "b4" "18.74" "19.78" "2...
4   "6" "666" "0.107" "b5" "5.79"...

5 rows × 1 columns
```

But it supposed to be `5 rows × 8 columns`

I already try:

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632075/how-to-read-file-with-space-separated-values-in-pandas)
[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-pandas-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace-for-irreg)

And I also try like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt",sep='\t',header=0)
```

But everything same. Can you please help to read the txt file as a dataframe.

Comment: Pandas thinks your file should look like `"2"delimiter"222"delimiter...` because you told it that there will be the word `delimiter` between each column; since your columns are separated by a space, not by the word `delimiter`, it is all one column. `\t` would work if there is a tab character. Your "CSV" would be read with `delimiter=' ', quotechar='"'`.

Comment: delimeter was a variable sorry I fix it in question. @Amadan

Comment: @BigBen I mention in the question I try already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `file.txt` content be

```
"uid" "raum_code" "tuerschild" "raumbezeichung" "raumflaeche" "raumumfang" "raumhoehe" "Comments"
"2" "222" "0.111" "Büro" "19.11" "17.96" "2.85" ""
"3" "333" "0.123" "Besprechungsraum" "42.79" "26.68" "2.85" ""
"4" "444" "0.105" "Büro" "17.28" "16.50" "2.85" ""
"5" "555" "0.106" "Büro" "18.74" "19.78" "2.88" ""
"6" "666" "0.107" "Fernmeldetechnik" "5.79" "9.93" "2.88" ""
```

observe that spaces are used for separating and everything (both string and numeric values) are quoted and first line is header, considering that suitable reading is

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt",sep=' ',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
print(df.shape)  # (5, 8)
print(df)
```

output

```
   uid  raum_code  tuerschild    raumbezeichung  raumflaeche  raumumfang  raumhoehe  Comments
0    2        222       0.111              Büro        19.11       17.96       2.85       NaN
1    3        333       0.123  Besprechungsraum        42.79       26.68       2.85       NaN
2    4        444       0.105              Büro        17.28       16.50       2.85       NaN
3    5        555       0.106              Büro        18.74       19.78       2.88       NaN
4    6        666       0.107  Fernmeldetechnik         5.79        9.93       2.88       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

i try this and it shows correct result

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", header=0, quotechar="\"", sep=" ")

print(df.columns)
print(df.shape) 
print(df)
```