# loading semi structured data to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this (from jq)

```
script_runtime{application="app1",runtime="1651394161"} 1651394161
folder_put_time{application="app1",runtime="1651394161"} 22
folder_get_time{application="app1",runtime="1651394161"} 128.544
folder_ls_time{application="app1",runtime="1651394161"} 3.868
folder_ls_count{application="app1",runtime="1651394161"} 5046
```

The dataframe should allow manipulation of each row to this:

```
script_runtime,app1,1651394161,1651394161
folder_put_time,app1,1651394161,22
```

Its in a textfile. How can I easily load it into pandas for data manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the .txt using pd.read_csv(), specifying a space as the separator ([similar StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19632099/5618434)). The result will be a two-column dataframe with the bracketed text in the first column, and the float in the second column.

```
df = pd.read_csv("textfile.txt", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
```

2. Parse the bracketed text into separate columns:

```
df['function'] = df[0].str.split("{",expand=True)[0]
df['application'] = df[0].str.split("\"",expand=True)[1]
df['runtime'] = df[0].str.split("\"",expand=True)[3]
```

The result is a dataframe looks like this:
[image]

If you want to drop the first column which contains the bracketed value:
`df = df.iloc[: , 1:]`

[image]

Full code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("textfile.txt", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")

df['function'] = df[0].str.split("{",expand=True)[0]
df['application'] = df[0].str.split("\"",expand=True)[1]
df['runtime'] = df[0].str.split("\"",expand=True)[3]

df = df.iloc[: , 1:]
```

Comment: Thanks! The output still shows as following : `>>> print(df[1:2])
                                                   0     1
1  folder_put_time{application="app1",runtime="16...  22.0`

Comment: Apologies, my parsing code was missing some elements. I've updated it above. Running `print(df[1:2])` now outputs the properly formatted columns.

Comment: Edited my post a bit. Rerunning this did separate it into two columns but I need to extract all

Comment: Thank you for doing that! I've edited my answer as well -- the code above should output those columns. If you're looking to remove the original first column with the three values that have been parsed, I've added that code too

Comment: I wondered if your question about extracting all the rows was because you are running `print(df[1:2])`. This will only print one row (the second one). If you want to print all the rows, you would run `print(df)`.