# Reading a complex, large text file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a *very* large text file which I am trying to load into jupyternotebook to perform analysis and etc..

But I can't seem to find a way to separate the columns? Thus far I have only had experience in working with hdf5 and csv files which are relatively easy to get a hang of.

I will attach a link to the data below,

https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-022-04496-5/MediaObjects/41586_2022_4496_MOESM3_ESM.txt

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('41586_2022_4496_MOESM3_ESM.txt', delimiter='\t')
print(df1.head(2))
```

result

```
       1    331.581577     -1.512106  17.774   2.143  -0.828   0.132     104.93    1092.57      45.54     7.355     1.359    -1.468     267695571003410291                   20111024-F5902-01-061    26.9  5520.3    40.0    3.951    0.116    1.581    0.430    2.296    0.188    0.339    0.041
0       2    332.300352     -1.566708   6.780   0...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
1       3    331.985497     -1.371940  18.426   1...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *How* to seperate the columns? Which columns? :ı

Comment: I mean that once I load the data in, I'm expecting to see 26 distinguished columns: each corresponding to a particular parameter like age, age uncertainty etc... but all of it is bunched up in a single column.

Comment: You propably didn't specift the delimiter. What's your delimiter in the `csv` file? You can specify one like this; `pd.read_csv('paths.txt', delimiter="|")`. Can't open your link since it's messed up. You should edit your question and state that there should be 26 columns. Large file, jupyter, etc. are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I get a ParserError when I try to specify a delimiter, and sorry! Here is the link that should work:

Comment: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41586-022-04496-5/MediaObjects/41586_2022_4496_MOESM3_ESM.txt

Comment: There's a a bunch of commented lines. Delete them by hand and try with the `delimiter="\t"` since it seems there's a tab between the columns.

Comment: Please include text as text, not images and especially not links to images. And please include a sample of the data format within the post, SO posts have to be self contained.

Comment: Ahh yes, I've tried that :( I edited the question and attached an image of what I get

Comment: @OverflownOverflow  next time you ask question, please post the code and the result as I edited in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tab in your CSV.
Change the delimiter.

```py
import pandas as pd

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633103/20307768
# '\s+': it says to expect one or more spaces. the matches will be as large as possible.
df1 = pd.read_csv('41586_2022_4496_MOESM3_ESM.txt', delimiter='\s+')
df1.head(2)
```