# ValueError: only single character unicode strings can be converted to Py_UCS4, got length 0

Tags: python, pandas

while running the following code I found an error as shown below

```
data= pd.read_csv("Filtered Data.csv", sep='', encoding='latin-1')
```

Error shown:  `ValueError: only single character unicode strings can be converted to Py_UCS4, got length 0`

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Obviously that depends on the file you are analising. Provide it as well, or at least the piece of it where the error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure you have the encoding right?

Comment: What does this error actually mean ? I never found such type of error while importing csv before!

Answer (score 10):

The error is thrown because of `sep=''` It's missing a space. You can use `sep=' '`. 
Sep takes a string argument ([according to Panda documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)). So it's complaining about an empty string.

You can also use `delim_whitespace`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace).