# How to deal with multi-value lineterminators in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have the `\x02\n` as a line terminator in a csv file I'm trying to parse. However, I cannot use two characters in pandas, it only allows one, for example:

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\x01", lineterminator="\x02")
>>> data.loc[100].tolist()
['\n1475226000146', '1464606', 'Juvenile', '1', 'http://itunes.apple.com/artist/juvenile/id1464606?uo=5', '1']
```

Or:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\x01", lineterminator="\n")
 >>> data.loc[100].tolist()
['1475226000146', '1464606', 'Juvenile', '1', 'http://itunes.apple.com/artist/juvenile/id1464606?uo=5', '1\x02']
```

Here we can see that the `\n` hasn't been chopped off correctly. What would be the best way to read the csv file in pandas with the above separator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15026698/3350428

Comment: Do all lines have "\x02\n" as the line terminator?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov that's the delimiter, not the lineterminator. Is it the same?

Comment: @coldspeed yes, in this file. But I do have other files with different multi-value separators, so I don't just want to do a find-all/replace, etc.

Comment: That complicates things. There isn't any real support for this as of now.

Comment: @coldspeed I suppose the best thing to do here would be to use the first character as the line terminator, and the second to strip from the first value in the column?

Comment: That would've been my answer, but it will not work for your other CSVs...

Comment: @coldspeed if you want to post that answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of v0.23, pandas does not support multi-character line-terminators. Your code currently returns:

```
s = "this\x01is\x01test\x02\nthis\x01is\x01test2\x02"
df = pd.read_csv(
    pd.compat.StringIO(s), sep="\x01", lineterminator="\x02", header=None)

df
        0   1      2
0    this  is   test
1  \nthis  is  test2
```

Your only option (as of now) is to remove the leading whitespace from the first column. You can do this with `str.lstrip`.

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.lstrip()
# Alternatively,
# df.iloc[:, 0] = [s.lstrip() for s in df.iloc[:, 0]]

df

      0   1      2
0  this  is   test
1  this  is  test2
```

If you have to handle stripping of multiple other kinds of line-terminators (besides just the newline), you can pass a string of them:

```
line_terminators = ['\n', ...]
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.lstrip(''.join(line_terminators))
```

Comment: thanks man. Any interest in a job in a job or internship (our company is in the LA area)?

Comment: instead of the blank `lstrip`, I used the characters in the line_terminator I had, so something like: `df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.lstrip(''.join(self.line_terminator[1:]))`

Comment: @David542 Are you David from Premier Digital? :-) I really appreciate your offer, but I already have an on-campus job for the coming spring, and will be joining Google once I graduate. I am not currently looking to interview for any positions, but if that changes I'll be sure to give you a ping!

Comment: @David542 Okay, so you have a list of line-terminators? I can modify my solution.