# How to make read_csv more flexibile with numbers and whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read a `txt.file` with Pandas and the Problem is the seperator/delimiter consits of a number and Minimum two blanks afterwards.

I already tried it similiar to this code ([How to make separator in pandas read_csv more flexible wrt whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-pandas-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace)):

```
pd.read_csv("whitespace.txt", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
```

This is only working if there is only a blank or more. So I adjustet it to the following code.

```
delimiter=r"\d\s\s+"
```

But this is seperating my dataframe when it sees two blanks or more, but i strictly Need the number before it followed by at least two blanks, anyone has an idea how to fix it?

My data Looks as follows:

```
I am an example of a dataframe
I have Problems to get read
100,00
So How can I read it
20,00
```

so the first row should be:
`I am an example of a dataframe I have Problems to get read 100,00`
followed by the second row:
`So HOw can I read it 20,00`

Comment: Is the separator number a specific number?

Comment: the number can change

Comment: try this parameter : `delim_whitespace=True`

Comment: this leeds to every word /number in a new column....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id try it like this.

Id manipulate the text file before I attempt to parse it to a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

f = open("whitespace.txt", "r")
g = f.read().replace("\n", " ")

prepared_text = re.sub(r'(\d+,\d+)', r'\1@', g)

df = pd.DataFrame({'My columns':prepared_text.split('@')})
print(df)
```

This gives the following:

```
                                          My columns
0  I am an example of a dataframe I have Problems...
1                         So How can I read it 20,00
2
```

I guess this'd suffice as long as the input file wasnt too large but using the re module and substitiution gives you the control you seek.

The (\d+,\d+) parentheses mark a group which we want to match. We're basically matching any of your numbers in your text file.
Then we use the \1 which is called a backreference to the matched group which is referred to when specifying a replacement. So \d+,\d+ is replaced by \d+,\d+@.

Then we use the inserted character as a delimiter.

There are some good examples here:

https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub

Comment: it is working out, could oyu explain what excatly the Syntax after re.Sub means?