# pandas read_csv quote issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like this:

```
## df
Col1     Col2                  Col3
A234     
B678     "L" shaped, cool        41
```

The delimiter is `\t`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = "\t", dtype = str, quotechar = '""')
```

This is not correct.
Otherwise, I tried to import using `R` language `data.table`.

```
> df <- fread(filename, sep = "\t")

Found and resolved improper quoting out-of-sample.
>>. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

Any solution on Python?

Or I need to use `csv` package with argument `quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL`.

text file looks:  (you can copy below into a text document)

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A234        
B678    "L" shaped, cool    41
```

Comment: There are some spaces in `"L" shaped, cool`, leading to the improper output

Comment: yes. That is an issue. `R` language `data.table`'s `fread()` can handle this issue successfully. Any solution on Python?

Comment: According to [How to make separator in pandas read_csv more flexible wrt whitespace, for irregular separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026698/how-to-make-separator-in-pandas-read-csv-more-flexible-wrt-whitespace-for-irreg), perhaps `delim_whitespace=True` may help.

Comment: Could you provide the string of sample csv with original separator?

Comment: You have extra " in quotechar. try `pd.read_csv(filename, sep = "\t", dtype = str, quotechar = '"')`   If this doesn't work, could you explain "This is not correct."?  error? what is the output you get?

Comment: import csv   ;   
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a possible issue is the use of 4 spaces instead of a `\t` in your file. A possible solution is to use the `sep` to explicitly indicate that 4 spaces must be used a separator:

```
  df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" "*4, engine="python")  # Explicit engine to avoid ParserWarning
```